# Ionic 2 angular 2 Plotly.js issue

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 and angular 2. I install npm plotly.js and when i use  "import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly';" and use Plotly.newPlot(); it response me blank white screen without any error. What should i do?

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly';
Plotly.newPlot();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not see an errors, try checking the html element you use for the plot. I had a similar problem when using a plot inside a ion-card and the div for the plot ended up with a hight of 0 px.
You can solve this problem setting the hight of your div to px insted of % or setting the hight of the card manually.